# How to write a bulletproof Backbone js manager? (or fix delegated events in this example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm writing an app that will be extended by a team with varied experience, so I'm trying to limit Backbone's flexibility in order to provide a consistent way to structure our code.  To do that, I wrote a simple facade that hides the classes and instances behind get/set functions so classes/instances can't be overwritten unintentionally, and we use local vs. global variables, and our code stays prettier, and there's less maintenance.

My prototype code has been running great so far with one exception - in subclassed views the "events" property isn't delegating events.  If you see what's broken, I'd greatly appreciate it!  If you know a better way to organize the code to achieve the same ends, I'm open to that too!

Thanks!

A temporary example of the code running at: http://jiggler.media.mit.edu:8008/projects/2147302/?mode=player, and the subclassed view at http://jiggler.media.mit.edu/adam/scratchr2/static/js/project.js.  There is a fair amount in the running code that's unrelated, so I pulled out the relevant logic below.

Running backbone 0.9.2, underscore 1.3.3, and jQuery 1.7.1

```
// Facade factory - creates an interface for working with views
window.scratch={};
scratch.createBackboneManager=function(type,optionsObj){
  if (!type || !Backbone[type]) throw 'type required to add a backbone type (e.g., Model, View) to scratch';
  if(scratch[type]) throw 'scratch.'+type+' already exists';
  scratch[type]=(function(){
    var classes={};
    function create(name,classObj){
      if (classes[name]) throw type+' '+ name + ' already exists.';
      if (name[0].toUpperCase()!==name[0]) throw type+' names must be upper case. "'+name+'" starts lower case.';
      return classes[name]=(function(){
        var instances={},
            Klass = (classes[classObj.extendsClass]||Backbone[type]).extend(classObj);
        function createInstance(name,options){
          if (instances[name]) throw 'Instance '+ name + ' already exists';
          if (name[0].toLowerCase()!==name[0]) throw 'Instance names must be upper case. "'+name+'" starts upper case.';
          return instances[name]=new Klass(options);
        };
        function getInstance(name){
          return instances[name];
        };
        return $.extend(Klass,{getInstance:getInstance,createInstance:createInstance}) // return the Class with simple instance management methods.
      })();
    };
    function get(name){
      return classes[name]||undefined;
    };
    return $.extend({create:create,get:get},optionsObj);
  })();
};

// create managers
scratch.createBackboneManager('View');
scratch.createBackboneManager('Model');

// create a model
scratch.Model.create('Project',{
  defaults: {// current project
    owner: null, // instance of user?
    parentId: null,
    title: 'Untitled',
    isPrivate: false,
  }
}).createInstance('project',{
  owner: 'foo',
  viewing_user:'bar',
  title:'baz',
  id: '12345', 
});

// create a view
scratch.View.create('Global_UI',{
  initialize:function(){
    var self=this;
    $(document).ready(function(){self.render()});
  },
}).createInstance('global_ui');

// subclass the view and add events
scratch.View.create('Showcase',{
  extendsClass:'Global_UI',
  events: {
    "mouseover .see-inside"         : 'alertSee',

  },
  alertSee:function(e){alert(e)},

}).createInstance('showcase',{
  el:document.getElementById('project'),
  model:scratch.Model.get('Project').getInstance('project')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty convoluted to diagnose without a working example in a jsfiddle or something like that, but are you sure you don't want this...

```
Klass = (classes[classObj.extendsClass]||Backbone[type]).extend(classObj);
```

...to be this?...

```
Klass = (

  classes[ classObj.extendsClass ] || Backbone[ type ]

).extend( classObj );
```

Comment: Thanks JMM.  Basically it's trying to do:
    var SuperKlass = Backbone.View.extend({stuff});
    var SubClass = SuperKlass.extend({stuff});

So using Backbone[type] would extend Backbone.View instead of SuperKlass.  I'm creating a jsFiddle now.

Comment: Yeah, of course, my bad. Sorry, I screwed that up. I udpated the answer with what I meant, and then realized that's what you have -- I missed your parens around `classes[classObj.extendsClass]||Backbone[type]`. That's what I thought I noticed being amiss, so I'm back to square one.

Comment: No worries.  Here's the JS fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/a_laughlin/96SfZ/   Note that it works.  Even the case that's supposed to be broken works.  Now to figure out what's different...

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for suggesting the jsFiddle example.  Figuring out the difference made me realize the problem... setting events on non-existent elements works poorly.  Heh.  Forehead smacker, this one.

Comment: Ah, of course (non-existent element). Yeah, simplifying it to show someone else often helps narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to place your instance creation inside $(document).ready() call, else the elements won't exist for getElementById() calls.

Doh!